# Different form is loaded depending on user input

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

I'm creating a website page which has to different forms, depending on user input a different form is loaded.

When the page is loaded, The user is asked if they would like to register has a customer or a seller. depending on that choice I would the variable set to True or False a relevant form is loaded, so far I managed to get this much done but the page is only loading the background colour only nothing else(This started occurring  when I started introduce JavaScript)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

```
    <title>Customer/Reseller</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

    <!--[if IE]>

    <style type="text/css">
    .clear {
      zoom: 1;
      display: block;
    }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div class="section" id="page"> <!-- Defining the #page section with the section tag -->

        <div class="header"> <!-- Defining the header section of the page with the appropriate tag -->

            <h2>G51 Villain Supply</h2>
            <h3>Delivering Technology  </h3>

            <div class="nav clear"> <!-- The nav link semantically marks your main site navigation -->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html"> About </a></li>
                    <li><a href="products.html"> Products </a></li>
                    <li><a href="app.html"> Customer/Reseller </a></li>
                     <li><a href="private.html"> Private </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="section" id="articles"> <!-- A new section with the articles -->

            <!--start -->
            <div class="line"></div>  <!-- Dividing line -->
            <div class="article" > <!-- The new article tag. The id is supplied so it can be scrolled into view. -->
                <h2>Seller Section</h2>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="articleBody clear">


        <form action="" method="seller">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Seller Registration Form</legend>
                <br>Please complete </br>
                <br><label for="Fname">First Name:</label></br> <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
                <br><label for="Lname">Last Name:</label></br> <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
                <br><label for="Contact">Contact Number:</label></br> <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
                <br><label for="email">Email:</label></br> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> 
                <p></p><p></p>
                <p><label for="agree">&#160;</label> <input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree" /> The information I have provided above is accurate.</p>
                <p><label for="btnsubmit">&#160;</label><input type="submit" value="Register" name="btnsubmit" id="btnsubmit" /></p>
                <p></p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>                 
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- end -->
        </div>

         <div class="section" id="articles"> <!-- A new section with the articles -->
            <!--start -->
            <div class="line"></div>  <!-- Dividing line -->

            <div class="article" > <!-- The new article tag. The id is supplied so it can be scrolled into view. -->
                <h2>Customers Section</h2>

                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="articleBody clear">
        <form action="" method="cust">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Customer Registration Form</legend>
                    <br>Please complete </br>
                    <br><label for="Fname">First Name:</label></br> <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
                    <br><label for="Lname">Last Name:</label></br> <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
                    <br><label for="FAdd">First Line Address:</label></br> <input type="text" name="1stAdd" id="name"/>
                    <br><label for="PstAdd">Postcode:</label></br> <input type="text" name="PstAdd" id="name"/>
                    <br><label for="Contact">Contact Number:</label></br> <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
                    <br><label for="email">Email:</label></br> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> 
                    <p></p><p></p>
                    <p><label for="agree">&#160;</label> <input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree" /> The information I have provided above is accurate.</p>
                    <p><label for="btnsubmit">&#160;</label><input type="submit" value="Register" name="btnsubmit" id="btnsubmit" /></p>
                    <p></p>
                </fieldset>
        </form>                 
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end -->
        </div>

  <div class="footer"> <!-- Marking the footer section -->
      <div class="line"></div>
       <p>Copyright 2012 - G51 Villain Supply </p> <!-- Change the copyright notice -->
       <a href="#" class="up">Go UP</a>
    </div>

</div> <!-- Closing the #page section -->

</body>
```

some blocks of the JavaScript is uncompleted since I don't know how. please help, Thank you.

Edit:I replaced the above code with clean working one with out JavaScript.

Comment: I have replaced the code the clean one, working one. cheers

Comment: lol, what about lot of spaces between lines?

Comment: edited :). sorry little messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this one, it's working (tidied up and fixed) :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>
            Customer/Reseller
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" /><!--[if IE]>

    <style type="text/css">
    .clear {
      zoom: 1;
      display: block;
    }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="section" id="page">
            <!-- Defining the #page section with the section tag -->
            <div class="header">
                <!-- Defining the header section of the page with the appropriate tag -->
                <h2>
                    G51 Villain Supply
                </h2>
                <h3>
                    Delivering Technology
                </h3>
                <div class="nav clear">
                    <!-- The nav link semantically marks your main site navigation -->
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="about.html">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="products.html">Products</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="app.html">Customer/Reseller</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="private.html">Private</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div><input type="button" value="I'm a customer" onclick="document.getElementById('customerz').style.visibility='visible';document.getElementById('sellerz').style.display='none';" />
            <input type="button" value="I'm a seller" onclick="document.getElementById('sellerz').style.visibility='visible';document.getElementById('customerz').style.visibility='none';">
            <div id="sellerz" style='visibility:hidden;'>
                <div class="section" id="articles">
                    <!-- A new section with the articles -->
                    <!--start -->
                    <div class="line"></div><!-- Dividing line -->
                    <div class="article">
                        <!-- The new article tag. The id is supplied so it can be scrolled into view. -->
                        <h2>
                            Seller Section
                        </h2>
                        <div class="line"></div>
                        <div class="articleBody clear">
                            <form action="" method="seller">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <legend>Seller Registration Form</legend><br />
                                    Please complete<br />
                                    <br />
                                    <label for="Fname">First Name:</label><br />
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
                                    <label for="Lname">Last Name:</label><br />
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
                                    <label for="Contact">Contact Number:</label><br />
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
                                    <label for="email">Email:</label><br />
                                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                                    <p>
                                        <label for="agree">&nbsp;</label> <input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree" /> The information I have provided above is accurate.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        <label for="btnsubmit">&nbsp;</label><input type="submit" value="Register" name="btnsubmit" id="btnsubmit" />
                                    </p>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="customerz" style='visibility:hidden;'>
                <div class="section" id="articles">
                    <!-- A new section with the articles -->
                    <!--start -->
                    <div class="line"></div><!-- Dividing line -->
                    <div class="article">
                        <!-- The new article tag. The id is supplied so it can be scrolled into view. -->
                        <h2>
                            Customers Section
                        </h2>
                        <div class="line"></div>
                        <div class="articleBody clear">
                            <form action="" method="cust">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <legend>Customer Registration Form</legend><br />
                                    Please complete<br />
                                    <br />
                                    <label for="Fname">First Name:</label><br />
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
                                    <label for="Lname">Last Name:</label><br />
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
                                    <label for="FAdd">First Line Address:</label><br />
                                    <input type="text" name="1stAdd" id="name" /><br />
                                    <label for="PstAdd">Postcode:</label><br />
                                    <input type="text" name="PstAdd" id="name" /><br />
                                    <label for="Contact">Contact Number:</label><br />
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
                                    <label for="email">Email:</label><br />
                                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                                    <p>
                                        <label for="agree">&nbsp;</label> <input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree" /> The information I have provided above is accurate.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        <label for="btnsubmit">&nbsp;</label><input type="submit" value="Register" name="btnsubmit" id="btnsubmit" />
                                    </p>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end -->
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    <!-- Marking the footer section -->
                    <div class="line"></div>
                    <p>
                        Copyright 2012 - G51 Villain Supply
                    </p><!-- Change the copyright notice -->
                    <a href="#" class="up">Go UP</a>
                </div>
            </div><!-- Closing the #page section -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The JavaScript doing the trick :**

```
<input type="button" value="I'm a customer" onclick="document.getElementById('customerz').style.visibility='visible';document.getElementById('sellerz').style.display='none';" />
<input type="button" value="I'm a seller" onclick="document.getElementById('sellerz').style.visibility='visible';document.getElementById('customerz').style.visibility='none';">
```

**What else...?**

Well, I just wrapped each section in a separate `div` : the customer section in `customerz` and the seller section in `sellerz`

---

Have fun! ;-)

Comment: Thank You for being so helpful.

Answer (score 2):

this is the wrong way to do this. You should not try to declare the entire page inside a script block!!!. Instead use the following pseudocode :

```
<html>
  <head>
     <!-- Head content goes here -->
     <script type="text/javascript">

     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- body content -->
     <div id="chooser" class="chooserclass">
       <input type="checkbox" id="buyer" onclick="chooseBuyer()">Buyer</input>
       <input type="checkbox" id="seller" onclick="chooseSeller()">Seller</input>         
     </div>
     <div id="form1" class="form1css"> </div>
     <div id="form2" class="form2css"> </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Now in your script you have to do the following algorithm :

1. Both `form1css` and `form2css` should initially be set to "display:none" like this :
   `document.getElementById("form1").style.display="none"`

   **Build a chooseBuyer() function doing this :**
2. As you can see in html I have used two checkboxes. When the user chooses buyer checkbox, 
       (a) set `document.getElementById("form1").style.display="block"` 
   (b) set the other checkbox to be unchecked. 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            `document.getElementById("seller").checked="false"`

Similarly implement the chooseSeller() function using the inverse logic.